# Generate random integers from /dev/random

Tags: r, random

This is not homework. I would like to generate a random integer sequence (50 digits between 0:9) from /dev/random in R. I have a [hardware entropy key](http://www.entropykey.co.uk/).

I have found two "ideas", neither of which I can get to supply me with the numbers I am after:

1) [RDieHarder](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RDieHarder/index.html). Seems to allow access to /dev/random, but I cannot get it to produce the integer sequence that I require. e.g.

```
>library(RDieHarder)  
>x  <-dieharder(rng="/dev/urandom", psample=50) #urandom used for example
```

2) The [accuracy package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/accuracy/index.html) can supply true random numbers, but appears to be out of date and I can't see how to just sequence from /dev/random. e.g.

```
>library(accuracy)
>x=runifT(50)
```

Yes I have read Knuth etc and understand the problems of TRNGs (hence the hardware entropy key).

Any other ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What does your key generate on /dev/random? Random bytes (0-255)?

Comment: You can find all the details on the hyperlink given in the question. I understand it feeds /dev/random with entropy to stop it blocking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how to read from a dev and get n numbers from a to b inclusive:

```
readRandom <- function(n,a,b,dev="/dev/urandom"){
  size = b-a + 1
  rng = file(dev,"rb") # open connection
  nums = readBin(rng,what="integer",n=n) # read some 8-byte integers 
  close(rng) # close the connection
  return( a + nums %% size ) # reduce range and shift
}
```

If I read from /dev/random it blocks since my system runs out of entropy, but your key should be busy feeding entropy into the system, I think....

The 'edge' effect problem is as follows. Suppose I generate random integers from 0 to 10, but you want integers from 0 to 6. Then X %% 7 would generate twice as many 0,1,2,3 values, because the mapping is this:

```
> (0:10) %% 7
 [1] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 0 1 2 3
```

Now readBin is getting 8-bit integers, which are huge, so the odd few extra numbers at the end of the sequence shouldn't make much difference...

Comment: I don't quite understand it, but it's very interesting. Thanks.

Comment: One final question. If I want say numbers from 1:5, is your code easily adapted? It's not obvious to me how to change that aspect. Many thanks.

Comment: Ummm don't. There's a tiny 'edge effect' in my code. I think... Gimme a minute...

Answer (score 3):

Well, it's a late answer, but I found this via google so someone else might as well.

The code to do this is actually pretty simple. (Only two of the lines below are actually necessary.)

```
entropy <- file('/dev/urandom', 'rb')                           #rb = read binary .. try `cat /dev/urandom` at the command line to see what this "binary" output looks like if you don't encode it rationally
print(entropy)                                                  #you don't need to run this but reading it will help you understand what's going on
?readLines                                                      #again just to explain what's going on and what the other options, like scan(), do
readBin(entropy, what='integer')            #print random numbers from environmental noise
set.seed(readBin(entropy,1L))               #a truly random beginning to your R session…
```

In one line:

```
file('/dev/urandom', 'rb') %>% readBin('integer')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [random](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/random.html) package (which is also on [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/package=random)) which retrieves data from a hardware RNG at [random.org](http://www.random.org).

```
R> library(random)
R> randomNumbers(n=50,min=1,max=9,col=5)
      V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
 [1,]  8  7  4  6  3
 [2,]  4  8  3  6  8
 [3,]  5  2  9  1  6
 [4,]  9  5  6  5  5
 [5,]  2  2  1  3  7
 [6,]  6  3  9  7  5
 [7,]  7  9  1  9  9
 [8,]  5  9  1  3  8
 [9,]  8  2  9  3  7
[10,]  6  1  1  8  7
R>
```

Comment: Hi Dirk. You were going to get an email. I did see that, but I want access to /dev/random, so not quite what I am looking for. Thanks. Excellent package though.